# Multiplication without loop or matrixes

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have two vectors of sizes `n` and `m`

```
a = [a1 a2 ... an];
b = [b1 b2 ... bm];
```

and I want to "multiply" them to obtain the result:

```
c =
     a1*b1 a1*b2 ... a1*bm
     a2*b1 a2*b2 ... a2*bm
     .     .         .
     .     .         . 
     an*b1 an*b2 ... an*bm
```

Is there any simple way to obtain such result without resorting to loops or matrixes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Apply [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to the column version of `a` and the row version of `b`:

   ```
   a = 1:3; %// example input
   b = 10:10:40; %// example input
   c = bsxfun(@times, a(:), b(:).'); %'// or bsxfun(@times, b(:).', a(:));
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   c =
       10    20    30    40
       20    40    60    80
       30    60    90   120
   ```
2. Or, possibly faster, use [matrix multiplication](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) of `a` as a column vector times `b` as a row vector, in that order:

   ```
   c = a(:)*b(:).';
   ```
3. What you want can also be interpreted as a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), so you can use [`kron`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

   ```
   c = kron(a(:), b(:).'); %'// or kron(b(:).', a(:))
   ```

Comment: You already put the matrix multiplication, I'll remove my answer.